# Vuetify - v-select hidden inside v-stepper inside v-dialog

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to keep the v-select menu attached to the v-select but in the meantime also have it over the dialog when open, in the bellow codepen you can see that the Age dropdown is hidden inside its container and I can't figure out how to make it visible

I have this hierarchy of v-dialog -> v-stepper -> v-select

```
<v-select
  attach
  :items="['0-17', '18-29', '30-54', '54+', '60', '77']"
  label="Age*"
  required
></v-select>
```

https://codepen.io/amaieras/pen/VwWRzpL?editors=101

P.S. I don't want to remove the attach, the client wants it to be glued to the v-select :)

Answer (score 1):

Stepper component in vuetify has `overflow: hidden` style by default. You can change this property to `visible` in CSS:

```
.v-stepper,
.v-stepper__wrapper, 
.v-stepper__items {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

You can visit this [codepen](https://codepen.io/nimaebrazeh/pen/JjJzymo) too.

Comment: Awesome, is it possible to get the select menu go over the dialog footer as well? I want it to behave like it is not attached but still stay attached to the triggered element

Answer (score 1):

Because Modal has a fixed size.
And your `v-select` is almost at the bottom of modal.
If you move that field to top or middle, it will work for you.

Or you can make modal height larger than now.

Please add this css.

```
.v-menu__content .theme--light .menuable__content__active {
  position: initial !important;
}
```

this will work for you.

Comment: yeah, but why not make the v-select being a z-index more that the modal?

Comment: in that case, it will not work for you.
hmm, you can change the position of original v-menu__content with adding !important property.

Comment: Adding !important to what property?

Comment: just edited answer.

Comment: It looks better but it kind of moves everything below the menu, not making it overlap the content, but it's the best solution that I have so far